# Почему кортежи не имеют оператора []? C++

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, кортежи

Читаю про кортежи и задался вопросом, почему для них определена целая функция доступа к элементу std::get? Зачем так изголяться, почему у кортежа нет обычного оператора [] как у вектора, например? Это ведь тоже последовательный контейнер

P.S. Под "последовательным" я имею ввиду порядок доступа к элементам, а не их расположение в памяти.

Comment: потому что `operator[]` требует одинаковый тип, а кортежи - структуры с безымянными полями разных типов в общем случае...

Comment: @MaximTimakov получается, что автовыведение типов с возвратом auto с операторами не работает?

Comment: У любой функции тип возвращаемого значения строго один и задается он во время компиляции. А прописан ли он явно, или выводится посредством `auto` - не важно.